# How much unique data is there, put it all in a table

Tags: sql

I would like to query in `SQL` how many unique values ​​there are and how many rows are there. In `Python`, I could do it like this. But how do I do this in `SQL` so that I get the result like at the bottom?

[image]

In Python I could do the following

```
d = {'sellerid': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'modelnumber': [85, 45, 85, 12 ,85, 74, 85, 12]
     , 'modelgroup': [2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
display(df.head(10))
df['Dataframe']='df'

unique_sellerid = df['sellerid'].nunique()
print("unique_sellerid", unique_sellerid)

unique_modelnumber = df['modelnumber'].nunique()
print("unique_modelnumber", unique_modelnumber)

unique_modelgroup = df['modelgroup'].nunique()
print("unique_modelgroup", unique_modelgroup)

total_rows = df.shape[0]
print("total_rows", total_rows)

[OUT]
unique_sellerid 3
unique_modelnumber 4
unique_modelgroup 3
total_rows 8
```

I want a query like

[image]

---

Here is the dummy table

```
CREATE TABLE cars (
  sellerid INT NOT NULL,
  modelnumber INT NOT NULL,
  modelgroup INT,
);

INSERT INTO cars
    (sellerid , modelnumber,  modelgroup ) 
VALUES 
    (1, 85, 2),
    (1, 45, 3),
    (1, 85, 2),
      (2,   12, 1),
      (2,   85, 2),
      (3,   74, 3),
      (3,   85, 2),
      (3,   12, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `count(distinct column)` aggregation function like :

```
select
  count(distinct col1) as nunique_col1,
  count(distinct col2) as nunique_col2,
  count(1) as nb_rows
from database
```

Also in pandas, you can also apply the nunique() function on the dataset, rather than doing it on each column: `df.nunique()`

Comment: thanks for the answer. When I'm using this I got 
`must appear in the GROUP-BY clause or used in an aggregate function`. When I'm using the GROUP-BY 
I get a table with just `1` in each row.

Comment: Unrelated, but: that it's a myth that has never been true that `count(1)` is faster than `count(*)` if you expect that.

Comment: @AdrianaSaborowski: the query in this answer will not result in that error: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a23d77619d92c47c8762d50521bcf175

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name and @César Bouyssi my mistake. I'm sorry for the confusion! Thank you very much for the quick answer! It worked.